# Visual Studio Community Run command after git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-commit

every time I do a git commit I want to catch the repo log to a file, I want to publish the commit log to my website (internal page).

The git command is

```
git log --since='01-01-2019' > "$(ProjectDir)\Content\CurrentCommit.txt"
```

Because I don't know how to execute it after commit what I'm doing is to execute it at after build but I don't like it because it takes time and delays the program execution (and it isn't necessary to do it every time)

[image]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (specifically in this case, a post-commit hook) to run your command. Place your command in the file `.git/hooks/post-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
git log --since='01-01-2019' > "Content/CurrentCommit.txt"
```

You might need to adjust the directory of the file. The working directory of the git hook will be your repository root.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `post-commit` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). This is intended to be used for notification about commit. Hooks are located under the `.git/hooks` folder in your repo